transformation of parameter vector in constrained optimization using Hessian basis
Consider an unconstrained optimization problem, where the parameter vector $ \mathbf{x} $ can be thought of as a linear combination of unit vectors:
$
\mathbf{x} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i \mathbf{e}_i = \mathbf{E} \boldsymbol{\alpha}
$
where $ \mathbf{E} = [\mathbf{e}_1, \mathbf{e}_2, \dots, \mathbf{e}_n] $ are the standard unit vectors and $ \boldsymbol{\alpha} = [\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n]^T $ are the original parameters to be identified.
To improve the conditioning of the Hessian $ \mathbf{H} $, we switch to a new basis formed by the normalized eigenvectors of $ \mathbf{H} $:
$
\mathbf{H} \mathbf{v}_i = \lambda_i \mathbf{v}_i
$
where $ \mathbf{V} = [\mathbf{v}_1, \dots, \mathbf{v}_n] $ are the eigenvectors and $\lambda_i $ are the corresponding eigenvalues.
Now, the same parameter vector $ \mathbf{x} $ can be expressed as:
$
\mathbf{x} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_i \mathbf{v}_i = \mathbf{V} \boldsymbol{\beta}
$
where $ \boldsymbol{\beta} $ are the new parameters corresponding to the eigenvector basis.
I have sometimes experienced that this transformation of variables improves optimization performance by making the problem less ill-conditioned.
But is such a transformation also applicable for optim problems involving bounds and linear constraints?
$
\min_{\mathbf{x}} \, f(\mathbf{x}) \quad \text{subject to} \quad \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{b}, \quad \mathbf{l} \leq \mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{u}
$
I have no practical experience with this, but would you suggest such a strategy for better handling ill-conditioned problems? Any references where such transformations are described are also appreciated
